# Product of two left invertible elements is also left invertible in Semigroup

Tags: group-theory, semigroups, semiring

Consider a Semigroup $(M, \ast)$ with a neutral element $e$. Now I have to prove that all left invertible elements of $(M, \ast)$ form a sub-semigroup.

A left invertible element is an element whose left inverse exists; i.e., $a$ is left invertible if there exists an element $a'$ such that
$$a' \ast a=e.$$
Let us consider a set $A\subset M$ containing all left invertible elements. Let $a,b \in A;$ then there exist $a',b' \in M$ such that 
$$a' \ast a=e \ \  \text{and } \ b' \ast b=e$$
Now I have to prove that $a \ast b$ is also left invertible; i.e., there exists some $c \in M$ such that
$$c \ast (a \ast b) = e.$$
Now I don't know how to prove it. Maybe my statement is wrong -- i.e., set of invertible is sub-semigroup -- or maybe there is another way to prove it.

Comment: This is really very easy and I think you should try a bit harder to prove it yourself. You can use $b'$ and $a'$ to construct a left inverse of $a*b$.

Comment: **Spoiler:**   try $b^\prime a^\prime$

Comment: O got it. $b' \ast a'$ is left inverse of $a \ast b$. Thanks both of you

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In a semigroup with neutral element $e$, the left invertible elements form a sub-semigroup,

because if elements $a$ and $b$ have left inverses $a'$ and $b'$, respectively, in the semigroup,

then $a'*a$ and $b'*b=e$,

so $(b'*a')*(a*b)=b'*(a'*a)*b=b'*e*b=b'*b=e;$

i.e., $b'*a'$ is a left inverse of $a*b.$

Some refer to the opposite order of the inverses of $a$ and $b$ in the inverse of $a*b$ as the

[Socks-Shoes property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Product),

because you take off your socks and shoes in the opposite order you put them on.